# Inline preview overlays on top of the Markdown document in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I'm using RMarkdown on a new installation with RStudio. I'm finding that the inline preview is taking up the top two thirds of the text editor for my rmarkdown file. It's appearing, in addition to showing up inline below each paragraph, on top of the paragraphs.

It makes it hard to code or see any of the other work that I'm doing. The preview is fixed to the top of the screen and it stays there even when I scroll up and down in the document.

I can get rid of the inline preview by clicking clear all output.

I think this is probably a bug, but maybe not. I tried restarting RStudio and the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to Tools -> Global Options, a window will pop up. Select "R Markdown" on the left and you should see something like the below:

[image]

Half-way through, make sure "Show output inline for all R Markdown documents" is unchecked.

Comment: It's a tough one because I actually want to show the inline results below each chunk. I just don't want it to take the entire screen like it's doing

Comment: It will show in the HTML/PDF document that gets knitted, unless if you state `include=FALSE` or `results='hide'` in the code chunk options.

Comment: I think there might be a miscommunication about the bug. I'll try uninstalling and reinstalling rstudio